# Pointer of pointer arithmetic regarding matrices

Tags: c, pointers

I have a doubt regarding pointer of pointer arithmetic in C.
If we do

```
int ** ptr = 0x0;
printf("%p",ptr+=1);
```

The output will be ptr+(# of bytes needed for storing a pointer, in my case 8).
Now if we declare a matrix:

```
int A[100][50];
```

`A[0]` is a pointer of pointer.

`A[0]+1` will now point to A[0]+(# of bytes needed for storing an integer, in my case 4).

Why "normally" 8 bytes are added and now 4?
`A[0]+1` will point to `A[0][1]`, so it is useful, but how does it work?
Thank you!

Comment: `A[0]` is not a pointer of pointer. It decays to `int*`. `ptr` points to elements of size `*ptr` = `int*`, and `A[0]` as a pointer points to elements of size `*A[0]` = `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this program, run on a 64-bit machine (a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.6, with GCC 9.2.0 to be precise):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int A[100][50];
    printf("Size of void * = %zu and size of int = %zu\n", sizeof(void *), sizeof(int));
    printf("Given 'int A[100][50];\n");
    printf("Size of A       = %zu\n", sizeof(A));
    printf("Size of A[0]    = %zu\n", sizeof(A[0]));
    printf("Size of A[0][0] = %zu\n", sizeof(A[0][0]));
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Address of A[0]     = %p\n", (void *)A[0]);
    printf("Address of A[0] + 0 = %p\n", (void *)(A[0] + 0));
    printf("Address of A[0] + 1 = %p\n", (void *)(A[0] + 1));
    printf("Difference          = %td\n", (void *)(A[0] + 1) - (void *)(A[0] + 0));
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Address of &A[0]     = %p\n", (void *)&A[0]);
    printf("Address of &A[0] + 0 = %p\n", (void *)(&A[0] + 0));
    printf("Address of &A[0] + 1 = %p\n", (void *)(&A[0] + 1));
    printf("Difference           = %td\n", (void *)(&A[0] + 1) - (void *)(&A[0] + 0));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Size of void * = 8 and size of int = 4
Given 'int A[100][50];
Size of A       = 20000
Size of A[0]    = 200
Size of A[0][0] = 4

Address of A[0]     = 0x7ffee5b005e0
Address of A[0] + 0 = 0x7ffee5b005e0
Address of A[0] + 1 = 0x7ffee5b005e4
Difference          = 4

Address of &A[0]     = 0x7ffee5b005e0
Address of &A[0] + 0 = 0x7ffee5b005e0
Address of &A[0] + 1 = 0x7ffee5b006a8
Difference           = 200
```

Therefore, it is possible to deduce that `A[0]` is an array of 50 `int` — it is not a 'pointer of pointer'.  Nevertheless, when used in an expression such as `A[0] + 1`, it 'decays' into a 'pointer to `int`' (pointer to the type of the element of the array), and hence `A[0] + 1` is one integer's worth further through the array.

The last block of output shows that the address of an array has a different type — `int (*)[50]` in the case of `A[0]`.